# unDisable direct input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Inputs I'm creating are unDisabling all at once as the state changes.
How can I enable/disable direct input? Mb something wrong with refs... I dunno

```
class TaskRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = createRef();
    this.state = {
      edit: true,
    };
  }

  editTask = () => {
    this.setState({ edit: false })
  };

  render() {
    const { edit } = this.state;
    return (
    <div>
      <ul className="taskList">
        <div className="tasksContainer">
          {tasks.map(task => (
            <div className="taskDiv" key={task.id}>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed}/>
              <input
                ref={this.myRef}
                type="text"
                content={task.text}
                disabled={edit}
              />
              <button onClick={this.editTask}>Редактировать</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by "Mb smth wrong with refs... I dunno"?

Comment: Nothing wrong with Refs as they are not even used. You are sharing one state between all fields, that's why everyone is getting disabled at once.

Comment: so how do i need to change disable status of direct input?

Comment: Just posted an answer, see what i am trying to convey

Comment: @Vladislav Hope my answer helps too. Posted an example along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is in constructor,

```
const inputState = {};
tasks.forEach((task) => inputState[`input_${task.id}] = true)
this.state = {
  ...inputStates
}
```

Then in JSX

```
disabled={this.state[`input_${task.id}`]}

<button onClick={() => this.editTask(`input_${task.id})}>Редактировать</button>
```

Then in Function

```
editTask = (inputState) => {
  this.setState({ [inputState]: false })
};
```

I'm just giving you idea, Maintain separate states for each, set them apart. Look for spelling mistakes if any

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using single state i.e. `edit` for all the input fields. So, when the state is updated, its updated for all the fields. You have to use different  states for different input. One of the suggestion might be that, You can use array of boolean in the `edit` state update it according to the input fields actions

Answer (score 0):

Since you are binding all the inputs to the single `this.state.editTask` property, whenever you'll modify it, all inputs will change because all the inputs have their `disabled` attributes bound to `{this.editTask}`.

What you can do is that you can define an `edit` property in each task same as you're tackling the `complete` property for checkboxes.

Please see the [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8olmf3?file=Hello.js) I've created to see it working.

I.e. `tasks` would be:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    completed: true,
    edit: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    completed: false,
    edit: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    completed: true,
    edit: true
  }, {
    id: 4,
    completed: false,
    edit: true
  }, {
    id: 5,
    completed: true,
    edit: false
  }
]
```

And then you can bind the html in the following way:

```
<ul className="taskList">
        <div className="tasksContainer">
          {this.state.tasks.map(task => (
            <div className="taskDiv" key={task.id}>
              <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed}/>
              <input className='taskInput'
                type="text"
                content={task.text}
                disabled={task.edit !== true}
              />
              <button onClick={() => { this.editTask(task) }}>Редактировать</button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
```